# create Multiple Domains on Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

i have exchange server 2007 ,and i want to create two emails for each employee in ex.

bob@companyA.org 
bob@companyB.org

can anyone help me

thanks,

Comment: Did you try to do that using E-mail Address Policies ?
I think is the preferred way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This set of articles cover how to setup accept email for muliple domains and to setup the **E-Mail Address Policy**.

- http://www.petri.co.il/defining-exchange-2007-email-address-policy-part-1.htm
- http://www.petri.co.il/defining-exchange-2007-email-address-policy-part-2.htm